# Distinct Function C#

Tags: c#, distinct

Edit:
The original question was based on this code that I saw below elsewhere:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // List with duplicate elements.
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);
    list.Add(3);
    list.Add(3);
    list.Add(4);
    list.Add(4);
    list.Add(4);

    foreach (int value in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", value);
    }

    // Get distinct elements and convert into a list again.
    List<int> distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();

    foreach (int value in distinct)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", value);
    }
    }
}
```

I apologize for my question was not specific enough.

Comment: It does *none* of those things; you do not *know* that it does those things because *knowledge* must be *true*, and those are all *false*.  `Distinct` provides a *sequence of distinct elements* -- it does not modify the container at all.

Comment: it creates a new sequence with the distinct elements.  It doesn't delete anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distinct is similar to distinct in a SQL Query .

Ex: var `distinctElements = duplicatedElements.Distinct();`

The above code filters out duplicate entries and returns an `IEnumerable<T>` of distinct elements. The original duplicatedElements is left intact though

Comment: “returns a list” I would be careful about terminology here, because `Distinct()` doesn't return `List<T>` (or even `IList<T>`).

Comment: this is what I original meant,
`distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

`Distinct` does not do this, as Eric says.  Instead, it feeds you distinct elements of a container in an `IEnumerable<T>`.  The exact implementation of `Distinct` actually varies on the container.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
public static class StaticyGoodness
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var someAs = new List<A>();
        var someBs = new List<B>(); // get it?

        DoTheThings(someAs);
        // Doing things the regular way

        DoTheThings(someBs);
        // Doing things the SPECIALIZED way

        DoTheThings(someBs.OrderBy(b => b.Stuff));
        // Doing things the REALLY SPECIALIZED way
    }

    private static void DoTheThings<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing things the regular way");
    }

    private static void DoTheThings(this IEnumerable<B> source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing things the SPECIALIZED way");
    }

    private static void DoTheThings(this IOrderedEnumerable<B> source)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing things the REALLY SPECIALIZED way");
    }
}

public class A { }
public class B : A { public int Stuff { get; set; } }
```

Depending on what exactly you give to the `DoTheThings` function, a different overload gets bound at compile time.  **I found this surprising.**  I thought the runtime would choose a better candidate, if there was one, at runtime based on the thing's *actual* type instead of its *declared* type.

For example, if we extract the `OrderBy` expression to a local variable, declaring it as `IEnumerable<B>` instead of `IOrderedEnumerable<B>` (e.g. we are returning from a repository method but don't want to expose the implementation detail of its having been sorted), the REALLY SPECIALIZED call would not be made.

```
IEnumerable<B> plainEnumerable = someBs.OrderBy(b => b.Stuff);
DoTheThings(plainEnumerable);
// Doing things the SPECIALIZED way  :(  (ed.)
```

Comment: The implementation of `Distinct` is always the same (it's an extension method). How do you think the implementations could differ?

Comment: You're right, I misspoke.  I shouldn't say its implementation changes, I should say a different overload gets bound depending on what you put in.  Edited with example.  Would love to hear @EricLippert weigh in.  :)

Comment: That's just how C# as a statically typed language works. But this is nothing specific about `Distinct()`. It has two overloads like this (one for `IEnumerable<T>`, one for `IQueryable<T>`), but that's exactly the same for every other LINQ method.